# Synaptics touchpad on my Acer 4530 stop working

Tags: 10.10, touchpad, synaptics

i got my touchpad stop working after several hours being disabled (using Fn+F7 in my Acer 4530). i've tried many times to turn it on using the same key-combination (Fn+F7), although the touchpad indicator says it works, but the touchpad still not working

i wonder if anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: To avoid confusion, please edit your question title and tags to use "Synaptics". The graphical package manager that comes with Ubuntu is called "Synaptic" and your question is being presented in a list of package manager–related questions because of the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pardon me i forgot to answer your responses & answers. 
Actually my touchpad had came back to life again. 
I just re-installed the X11 then after reboot it works again. I didn't know what wrong here in my system

Comment: You should accept your own answer (or whichever you like) so that this is shown as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: oh ok thx, i'm a n00b here

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, touchpad worked for login screen but not once logged in. I got it going with

```
gconftool -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true
```

Comment: I'm offering another possible solution as information, in the hope it could help someone, since this solution alone did not work for me. touchpad_enabled was indeed set to false, but there was another setting described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/201198/touchpad-stops-working-after-login) which I had to enable. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on my Acer Extensa 5635th
Here I could take the touchpad running again because I have also installed Windows XP. In XP, the touchpad back on, switched to Ubuntu and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by disabling the touchpad with the button, then typing `gconftool -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/peripherals/touchpad/touchpad_enabled true`, then re-enabling the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

This works for me when I forget that the touchpad can be disabled, but not re-enabled again.